# How to check if radio button is selected using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i am new to web development. I created a simple test question in html5 where a user selects only one answer(using radio). This done in html and javascript. No backend. I want to make sure a radio button has been selected before moving to next question. If radio button wasn't selected, it displays an alert telling user must select an answer before moving forward.

Below is my code:

```
 <section>
  <p class="questions">Given points (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) select the formula to find the equation of the given line.</p>
  <div >
   <form class="answers">
     <input type="radio" name="radio" value="correct"> 
     <math xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
      <mrow>
       <mi> y</mi>
       <mo>=</mo>
       <mi>m</mi>
       <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
       <mi>x</mi>
       <mo>+</mo>
       <mi>b</mi>
      </mrow>
    </math>

    <!-- 2nc choice -->
     <input type="radio" name="radio" value="incorrect" > 
      <math xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
          <mrow>
            <mrow>
              <mo>(</mo>
              <mi>x</mi>
              <mo>-</mo>
              <mi>h</mi>
              <msup>
              <mo>)</mo>
              <mn>2</mn>
            </msup>
          </mrow>
            <mo>+</mo>
            <mrow>
              <mo>(</mo>
              <mi>y</mi>
              <mo>-</mo>
              <mi>k</mi>
              <msup>
                <mo>)</mo>
                <mn>2</mn>
              </msup>
            </mrow>
            <mo> = </mo>
            <mrow>
              <msup>
                <mi> r</mi>
                <mn>2</mn>
              </msup>
            </mrow>
         </mrow>
      </math> <br>

      <!-- 3rd choice -->
     <input type="radio" name="radio" value="incorrect"> 
      <math xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
       <mrow>
        <mrow>
          <mi>y</mi>
          <mo>-</mo>
          <msub>
            <mi>y</mi>
            <mn>1</mn>
          </msub>
        </mrow>
        <mo> = </mo>
        <mrow>
          <mi>m</mi>
          <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
          <mo>(</mo>
          <mi>x</mi>
          <mo>-</mo>
          <msub>
            <mi>x</mi>
            <mn>1</mn>
          </msub>
          <mo>)</mo>
        </mrow>

       </mrow>
      </math>

       <!--4th Choice -->
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="incorrect"> 
      <math xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"> 
        <mrow>
          <mrow>
          <mi>y</mi>
          <mo>-</mo>
          <msub><mi>y</mi><mn>2</mn></msub>
        </mrow>
        <mo> = </mo>
        <mrow>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
            <msub><mi>y</mi><mn> 2</mn></msub>
            <mo> - </mo><msub><mi> y</mi><mn> 1</mn></msub>
          </mrow>
            <mrow>
            <msub><mi>x</mi><mn> 2</mn></msub>
            <mo> - </mo><msub><mi> x</mi><mn> 1</mn></msub>
          </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>
          <!-- <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo> -->
          <mo>(</mo>
          <mi> x </mi>
          <mo> - </mo>
          <msub><mi> x</mi><mn>2</mn></msub>
          <mo>).</mo>
        </mrow>

        </mrow>
      </math>

     <br>
      <!-- submit button -->
     <input type="submit" value="Submit & Next Question" onclick="getAnswer1(this.form)">
     <!-- clears the radio -->
     <input type="submit" value="Cancel & Clear Selection" onclick="">
   </form>
 </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I know my javascript code is wrong.. 
Javascript:

```
 /**Trouble making sure user selects an input doesn't matter if its wrong or right. An alert should displayed if user attempts to go to next question. Must select an option. **/
//global array stores answers
var results = [];
function getAnswer1(form) {
  var radios = form.elements['radio'];
   for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if(radios[i].checked) {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your HTML has `name="radio"`, but your Javascript has `form.elements['radios']`. The extra `s` in the JS makes it not work.

Comment: @Bamar oh yes i rectified that thanks will make an update in the post

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector` to find the checked box and get its value.

```
function getAnswer1(form) {
    var checked = form.querySelector("input[type=radio]:checked");
    var value;
    if (!checked) {
        alert("You need to select one of the options");
        return;
    } else {
        value = checked.value;
    }
    results.push(value);
}
```

Also, to prevent the form from submitting when you click the `submit` button, change

```
onclick="getAnswer1(this.form)"
```

to:

```
onclick="getAnswer1(this.form; return false;"
```

Comment: i attempted to use Dennis Nerush sample below  i as need to store the result from the radio button in an array but when i tried to display the array on console it return empty. Please what did i do wrong

Comment: also what's the difference btwn querySelector and form.element['radio']

Comment: `querySelector` allows you to use CSS selector syntax to do more complex matching.

Comment: @user3497437 What array are you trying to display? Neither of our answers creates an array.

Comment: @Bamar thanks. But when i attempt to store the value in array for future reference the array returns empty when i try to view in the console

Comment: @Bamar i declared a global array to store the value 'correct' or 'incorrect' to show the results to the user when he/she is done.

Comment: I've changed the answer to push the value onto the array instead of returning it.

Comment: @Bamar why the change of OnClick() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105204/discussion-between-user3497437-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

```
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var value;
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].type === 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
        // get value, set checked flag or do whatever you need to
        value = radios[i].value;       
    }
}
```

Comment: if the radio button isn't checked and user attempts to submit without checking a button, how do i create an alert

Comment: After the for loop is done and the value variable is empty then it means that no radio button was selected. Then you can simply call alert("You have to choose an option");

Comment: You can break out of the loop when you find the value that's checked.

Comment: @DennisNerush i didn't use document.getElementsByTagName, i passed the form into the function and used the same approach similar to what u did but attempted to print the value on the console and it's returns empty

Comment: @DennisNerush Ignore my previous comment about `[type=radio]`. I thought you were using `querySelectorAll`, not `getElementsByTagName`.